# Netbeans 7 not starting up after python plugin installation

Tags: python, macos, netbeans

I went to tools, plugins. Then chose to install the three python items that show up. After installation. I choose the restart netbeans option. But instead of restarting, netbeans just closed. And now it is not opening. Any ideas how to fix this? I normally develop Java on my netbeans 7 install.

I am using a mac osx

I see there are no takers, so let me ask this: Is there a way to revert to before the new plugin install?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Netbeans would die before opening at all. I could not fix it, and had to revert back to 6.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps (picked form http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=198963)

Simple fix until the module is fixed:
From: http://blogs.oracle.com/gridbag/entry/disabling_a_netbeans_plugin_before
Modify:
C:\Users\your_user.netbeans\7.0\config\Modules\org-netbeans-modules-php-smarty.xml
Line 7 to false:

```
<param name="enabled">true</param>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but with Windows 7. I deleted the .netbeans directory located in my home folder. That fixed my problem, hope it fixes yours.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem with Netbeans 7 not starting. Netbeans had first errored out with no error message. Then it wouldn't start or give me an error. I looked in the .netbeans directory in my user directory, and found and attempted to delete the 'lock' file in that directory. When I first tried to delete it, it said it was in use. So with task manager, I had to go to processes tab and find netbeans. I killed that task, then was able to delete 'lock'. Then netbeans started.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem afther installing the python plguin. To solve this problem i deleted the file: ***org-openide-awt.jar*** from ***C:\Users\MYUSERNAME.netbeans\7.0\modules***

Regards!

Martín.

PD: I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 anda Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm not answering your question directly, but I too was considering installing the Python plugin in Netbeans 7 but saw that it was still in Beta.

I use WingIDE from wingware for Python development.  I'm a Python newbie but I'm told by the pros that Wing is the best IDE for Python.  The "101" version is free and works very well.  The licensed versions include more options such as version control integration and Django features.